# How can I get my computer to remember $PATH?

Tags: bash, packages

I am trying to make `php` and `composer` to be always available in terminal, and everyone is saying *make path global* and such, but when I do so and close terminal or I restart my computer, these settings are lost!

When I do the following:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin:$PATH
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

After doing so, I get:

```
❯ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php
❯ which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

But when I restart terminal or my computer, I need to re-do this again. Even-though this is what is in `.bash_profile`:

```
PHPMAMP="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin"
COMPOSER="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
PATH=$PATH:$PHPMAMP:\$COMPOSER
export PATH
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php'
alias laravel='~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel'
```

What I am doing wrong? Both `php` and `composer` are defined in `bash_profile`, but ignored when I restart my computer or terminal...

Comment: Are you using bash or zsh as your shell? You can check with `ps $$` (or `echo "$SHELL"`, but that can sometimes be misleading). Also, the backslash in `PATH=$PATH:$PHPMAMP:\$COMPOSER` will prevent it from working properly.

Comment: ps $$ returns:   PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND

Comment: echo "$SHELL" returns: /bin/zsh

Comment: @bart That is your problem then, `zsh` doesn't read `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile.`, you need to use `.zshrc` and `.zsh_profile` respectively.

Comment: Ok, why is that? Who decides that I use zsh? How can I tell "what I use" from command line?

Comment: @bart Are you using macOS? Mac changed its default shell from Bash to Zsh some years ago. You can change it if you want: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224511/how-to-use-bash-as-default-shell

Comment: @ruohola Yes, figured this out after a few hours, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you comments you are using Zsh. Zsh doesn't read `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile`, you need to use `.zshrc` and `.zsh_profile` respectively.

Note that `.zsh_profile` is only read for login shells. Namely, macOS Terminal.app starts Zsh as a login shell, other terminals on other operating systems likely do not. You need to set the aliases in `~/.zshrc` for them to be sourced for non-login shells.

Comment: I added all my paths to .bashrc, closed terminal, typed "which php" and it still didn't find PHP...

Comment: You need to use `$ type php` to see the alias, `which` only shows paths of programs.

Comment: Cool, I added everything (the above paths) to .bash_profile, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, because yes, I was using .zsh (unexpectedly, must have happened after MacOS upgrade). Placing the paths in .zshrc did the trick.